# AngularJS form not resetting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I've been trying so hard to make this work. I know about child scopes and prototypal inheritance and I'm also using the dot notation for the model but I can't get the form to reset. Please check [my form hosted here](http://dry-reef-3978.herokuapp.com/index.html#/?agent=a). The code
[is here](http://jsfiddle.net/zyv9j6qb/1/)
Please help me reset the form scope variable. This is how I'm doing it currently

```
                            if(data==1){
                            if($scope.form.language=='English'){
                                toastr.success('Form has been submitted successfully', 'Success');
                            }
                            else{
                                toastr.success('הטופס נקלט בהצלחה', 'הצלחה');
                            }
                            form={};
                            console.log('Empty is'+empty);
                        }
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. And here's how I initialize my form variable.

```
        .controller('formCtrl', function($scope,$location,$translate,$filter) {
        $scope.form={};
        $scope.currentLang='en';
        $scope.form.createdate=new Date();
```

Comment: the jsfiddle you provided is broken

Comment: Yeah that is just to show the code, it depended on a few things to work which I haven't attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `form={};` to `$scope.form = {};`

Also, since you haven't provided the context of your code snippet (i.e whether its in the angular digest cycle), if the form doesn't reset add `$scope.$apply();` just after `$scope.form = {};`

Comment: I'm doing `form={}` because the form scope variable is being passed in the submit function. I was getting confused about the scope so I thought that would be the most clear-cut way to get the right scope and do stuff with it.

Comment: how do I know whether it is in the digest cycle?

Comment: I've been literally banging my head against the wall but at the `$scope.$apply();` did it. I thought `$scope.$apply();` is only used when changes outside of angular are done or yeah outside of digest cycle. I don't know how to check if changes are in digest cycle or not.

Comment: Well, go read about how angular's digest cycle works. Basically, whatever, it keeps a watch on is in the digest cycle. Asynchronous requests is one example which are not in the digest cycle.